# Xcode upgrate problems from v4.5.2 to v4.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

I upgraded my xcode from v4.5.2 to v4.6.1 from then on I notice that all the applications that connect to a server is not connecting to those respective servers.. I tried to google this and was not successful in getting an apt solution.

Is there something i have to do? Anything i missing to understand here with respect to the update?

Any Suggestions would be more than helpful.

**EDIT : I didn't download the .dmg file from ios development center. I installed it from itunes.. I mean the mac appstore**

Comment: Tried to download from mac app store? If not. Take a look at [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

Comment: Whats the error you're seeing?

Comment: It says xmpp stream disconnected in one.. n other it just donest give any error message... Somehow either way doesnt connect to the servers

Comment: @Praveen... Thats how i have installed it.. from mac appstore..

Comment: It may be any kind of server problem. How many times have you tried?

Comment: No its not a server problem.. because I have my app in ipad that was deployed before the upgrade and it works fine